# Jest mockedCoeus.mockImplementation throws a TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using Jest to write a test and mock a function that calls an HTTP request.

```
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import * as pull from "../src/pull";
import fs = require("fs");

// read the reponse data from a file.
const response = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync("./__fixtures__/pr.json", "utf8")
);

// have jest mock the function and set it's response.
jest.mock("../src/pull");
const mockedCoeus = mocked(pull.getPullRequest, true);

mockedCoeus.mockImplementation(async () => {
  return response as any;
});

// write the test.
describe("#get details for a PR", () => {
  it("should load user data", async () => {
    const data = await pull.getPullRequest(165, "data-ios");
    expect(data).toBeDefined();
    expect(data.updated_at).toEqual("2020-04-10T16:46:30Z");
  });
});
```

The test passes, however, I get the following error when running `npm jest`

```
TypeError: mockedCoeus.mockImplementation is not a function
```

I've looked at other reported errors having to do with the placement of `jest.mock` however, it does not seem to be the case here. Why is this error thrown but the tests pass? How can I fix it?